# How can you scale out a Job that is already created?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes Job that has, for instance, parallelism set to 4. When this job is created, I might want to scale this out to, say, 8. But it seems like `edit`ing the Job and setting parallelism to 8 doesn't actually create more pods in the Job.

Am I missing something? Or is there no way to scale out a Job?

Answer (score 6):

So as per [job documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/jobs) you can still scale a Job running the following command:

```
kubectl scale job my-job --replicas=[VALUE]
```

Simple test shows that this option works right now as expected, but will be really deprecated in a future

> kubectl scale job is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future
>   version.
>
> The ability to use kubectl scale jobs is deprecated. All other scale
>   operations remain in place, but the ability to scale jobs will be
>   removed in a future release.

The reason is: [Deprecate kubectl scale job](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/60139)

Use below Job yaml as an example to create job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: test-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2010)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  completions: 1000
  parallelism: 5
```

Now lets test behavior:

```
kubectl describe jobs.batch test-job 
Parallelism:    5
Completions:    1000
Start Time:     Fri, 17 May 2019 16:58:36 +0200
Pods Statuses:  5 Running / 21 Succeeded / 0 Failed


kubectl get pods | grep test-job | grep Running
test-job-98mlv           1/1     Running     0          13s
test-job-fs2hb           1/1     Running     0          8s
test-job-l8n6v           1/1     Running     0          16s
test-job-lbh46           1/1     Running     0          13s
test-job-m8btl           1/1     Running     0          2s
```

Changing  parallelism with `kubectl scale`:

```
kubectl scale jobs.batch test-job --replicas=10

kubectl describe jobs.batch test-job
Parallelism:    10
Completions:    1000
Start Time:     Fri, 17 May 2019 16:58:36 +0200
Pods Statuses:  10 Running / 87 Succeeded / 0 Fail

kubectl get pods | grep test-job | grep Running
test-job-475zf           1/1     Running     0          10s
test-job-5k45h           1/1     Running     0          14s
test-job-8p99v           1/1     Running     0          22s
test-job-jtssp           1/1     Running     0          4s
test-job-ltx8f           1/1     Running     0          12s
test-job-mwnqb           1/1     Running     0          16s
test-job-n7t8b           1/1     Running     0          20s
test-job-p4bfs           1/1     Running     0          18s
test-job-vj8qw           1/1     Running     0          18s
test-job-wtjdl           1/1     Running     0          10s
```

And the last step that i believe will be the most interesting for you - you can always edit your job using [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) command

```
kubectl patch job test-job -p '{"spec":{"parallelism":15}}'

kubectl describe jobs.batch test-job
Parallelism:    15
Completions:    1000
Start Time:     Fri, 17 May 2019 16:58:36 +0200
Pods Statuses:  15 Running / 175 Succeeded / 0 Failed

kubectl get pods | grep test-job | grep Running | wc -l
15
```

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl scale` doesn't support `Job` resource anymore. Here is working solution for me:

- `kubectl edit job [JOB_NAME]`
- set `parallelism` field to appropriate value for you.

It will create new pods or will terminate existing ones.

Comment: Say I have 10 jobs running and I reduce parallelism to 5, is there a way to know which of the 10 jobs will be terminated? Or can this be manually specified somehow?

Comment: If changing `parallelism` doesn't create more pods for you, check if you have a [*fixed completion count job*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#controlling-parallelism): "For *fixed completion count* Jobs, the actual number of pods running in parallel will not exceed the number of remaining completions. Higher values of `.spec.parallelism` are effectively ignored."

Answer (score 2):

A bit old question, but since it has no accepted answer, here's the one I believe is the correct:

Since `scale --replicas=...` does not work for `jobs` anymore, the workaround is:

```
oc patch -n [namespace] job.batch/[jobname] -p '{"spec":{"parallelism":0}}'
```

or:

```
oc patch job -n [namespace] [jobname] -p '{"spec":{"parallelism":0}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `scale` command:

```
kubectl scale job my-job --replicas=[VALUE]
```

From [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/jobs):

> kubectl scale causes the number of concurrently-running Pods to
>   change. Specifically, it changes the value of parallelism to the
>   [VALUE] you specify.

Comment: That's deprecated and will be removed. Also, changing the value of parallelism to a higher value doesn't actually add additional pods.

Comment: Maybe `kubectl scale --replicas=[VALUE] job/my-job`. Or you're saying that `scale` is deprecating in general? I'm on the latest kubectl and don't see the deprecation notice.

Answer (score 1):

[`kubectl scale job`, deprecated since 1.10, has been removed in 1.15.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#cli)

Just use `kubectl edit job` to edit config yaml.

Answer (score -1):

kubectl patch cronjob  -p "{"spec":{"jobTemplate":{"spec":{"parallelism":0, "completions":0}}}}" -n

NOTE: On Windows, that outer quotes has to be a double quote. For OpenShift (OC command), it accepts single quotes